# What is the technical term (if one exists) for this kind of website design?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

I'm looking to define a website layout that's fairly common on a lot of websites but can never get the right word. The design is composed of generally a header banner (like StackExchange/Facebook/Twitter), a full width image, then seperate sections in a long-scroll. It's almost like an info-graphic on the web. Here's a few examples:

http://inky.com/

http://www.psd2html.com/

Comment: "One Page" is the common term. However, your second link is nowhere near a one page design.

Comment: Thanks Scott, what would you call the second one? I merely added it because it matched the patterns I was describing but with other pages "behind" the home page.

Comment: I've heard/seen the term 'infinite scrolling' used for sites that 'dynamically load' content as you scroll. It doesn't apply to the rest of the design elements you've mentioned though.

Comment: nice description, a screenshot would be welcome too before the links change forever or go down

Comment: Can you please include screenshots of the websites that you're asking about? If the site design changes or the link goes down, your question will be made much worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"One Page" is a common term to describe a web site which consists of primarily one single, long, page divided into various sections as you scroll downwards.

You can few some one page examples at : [OnePageLove.com](http://www.onepagelove.com)

You're second link doesn't really fit the "one page" model because, well it's many pages all linked to in the navigation.

I don't know that there is a specific term for a web site design which merely has a header, footer and center content. After all, wouldn't that pretty much describe every single web page out there?

Answer (score 3):

You might also look under **Parallax Scrolling** Websites

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is a site built on a Bootstrap framework. You can find the frame work here: http://getbootstrap.com/

Many developers are using it as it is easily customizable through checking boxes of the features you want. i.e. Responsive framework, Icons, Carousels, etc. You can customize and then download your options which contains the css, html, js and images for your site to be built on. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

I would be careful with using it as sites using Bootstrap tend look very similar but if that's the look you're going for then Bootstrap is a great place to start.