# New 'Scroll' Structured Websites

Tags: website-design, css

What's [this design style](http://beta.swipe.to/) used by so many new websites called?  If anyone wants to edit this post to use a different link feel free.  I'm just wondering how the CSS and such works for websites that have scrolling 'frames' like this.  I heard that this sort of thing is often done in Wordpress.  Full disclosure:  I know next to nothing about web development.

Comment: A scrollbar...? Or what specifically are you referring to? Keep in mind the coding of CSS is generally out of scope for this exchange.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the technical term (if one exists) for this kind of website design?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26879/what-is-the-technical-term-if-one-exists-for-this-kind-of-website-design)

Comment: My stock answer for this question: The style is called "annoying".

Comment: @DA01: that is hardly an objective comment ;) Scrolling is seen as the easiest way to navigate through content.

Comment: could you post a screenshot on-site before it's gone forever?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this style has a particular name. I believe its origin could be in [parallax scrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) sites, when you could use navigation buttons to "jump" to a portion of the the page that, as a section, used the whole screen height. They can also be referred to as *Single Page* sites, because most content is available on a single file.

Some examples of sites with similar color-block scrolling areas:

- http://ala.ch/
- http://www.endgame.com/ (parallax)
- http://www.adveris.fr/
- http://midyear.deakin.edu.au/#fee-freeze

Sites found on [Awwwards](http://www.awwwards.com/)

Answer (score 2):

In the agencies I worked in, we always called them "One-Pager".

The coding of these pages is very easy since, as @Yisela mentioned, all the content is stored in one file (mostly). In my opinion it doesn´t really make a difference whether you use a CMS or not. And since most of these pages have static content and are for promotional stuff that doesn´t change too often, CMS aren´t in use that often.

Answer (score 2):

1. They are called «Single-Page Websites».
2. The Animation Effect you see is called: «Parallax Scrolling»
3. The appearance has absolutely nothing to do with WordPress. You can do this with any CMS, or with no CMS at all.

Things to think about when using this kind of design:

1. It's already overused
2. Altough it's quite fast to create because you don't have to think about a content navigation strategy it's a bit harder to extend these kind of pages.
3. The biggest drawback is that you only have one link for the whole content, so it's harder to share specific content.

Comment: I´m not so sure about 2 and 3, while I agree that it´s hard to extend these kind of pages, you can still have a content navigation and share content with an internal anchor. 
But again, you mostly see these pages as microsites for projects or a presentation for agencies, so I think it is desired to start at the top and go down from there.

Comment: Sure. You can extend it with some anchor links. But entering a page somwhere down below isn't common sense, and can confuse users.